# cannot find /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

Tags: gcc, centos, libstdc++

I have updated my gcc to 4.7.2 just now but when I install a R package, it reports the error(below) but the file it need is actually there. Is there any idea how can I do?

```
/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-CentOS-linux/4.7.2/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RcppArmadillo'

[jingyi@CMP ~]$ ll /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Mar  5 21:49 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 975088 Feb 27  2014 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 976312 Jan  9  2013 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i doubt it's the reason for the failure, but your `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13` file really should have 755 perms

ignoring that, your toolchain path under `/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/`.  maybe check to see if there's a libstdc++ file under that root.  i.e. `/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so*`

if it still fails, try running the command under `strace -f -o log` and see if it shows you the actual path it's looking for.

Comment: Mike. Thanks for your answer. I have a file /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-CentOS-linux/4.7.2/32/libstdc++.so. But what should I do with it? Is it any conflict between 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: Hi Mike, I have relinked libstdc++.so.6 to libstdc++.so.6.0.8 and it works again!! But I still don't know what is the problem.